# html <script> tag headers

Tags: html, script-tag, custom-headers

I'm trying to require a script that is firewalled with a header authentication system and trying to find a way around it.

So far it's pretty evident that you can't add custom headers to the script tag its self but I have seen something about customizing the headers on the page before requesting or on the server side.

Until this point, I can't say I've seen any solid answers.

Comment: download the scipt, self-host it or use some free hosting service

Comment: I can't download it. This is script is part of a framework that has to be included from online

Comment: then I think you may have to talk with people who manage script holding server

Answer (score 3):

You can load it via xhr and `eval()` it in-page. For example with jQuery, you can use:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ - see `beforeSend` to set headers; use this to retrieve the file content.

Then use https://api.jquery.com/jquery.globaleval/ `globalEval()` to eval the gotten content in-page.

You could achieve the same with vanilla `HttpRequest` and `eval()`, but I was always too lazy to do it that way. Or maybe not... I just found a piece of code in the project I'm working:

```
var evalScript = function(e) {
  var h = evalScript.node,
      s = document.createElement("script");
  s.type = "text/javascript";
  s.text = e;
  h.appendChild(s);
  h.removeChild(s);
};
evalScript.node = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.getElementsByTagName("*")[0];
// TODO: make async
function loadJs(js) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("GET", js, false);
  req.send(null);
  evalScript(req.responseText);
}
```

Just add the headers to this.

Comment: I have implemented this code but I'm getting 'CORS' problems. I'll be speaking to the support tomorrow and I'll try and get this issue sorted and ill get back to your answer tomorrow. thank you

Comment: Yeap, they should add a CORS header. If not, from your comment below I see you can access the resource from the server (PHP). Worst case scenario, you can set up a proxy on your domain, like `/get_js.php?remote=<url>` that just echoes the content of the remote <url>. However this is not going to help a lot if the said scripts do ajax requests of their own to the remote server directly. Because this way (proxied) they run under your domain so they'll trip CORS when they try to access their domain just the same.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple Ajax function you could use to get the contents of the script:

```
function get(url, callback) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", url, true);
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState === 4) {
      if(this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
        callback.apply(this, [this.responseText, this]);
      } else {
        // something went wrong.
      }
    }
  };
  request.send();
}
```

Since you need to set custom headers, you'd also use the `request.setRequestHeader` method, like this:

```
function get(url, callback) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", url, true);
  // BEGIN: CUSTOM HEADERS
  request.setRequestHeader("Header-Name", "header/value");
  request.setRequestHeader("Other-Header", "other/value");
  // END: CUSTOM HEADERS
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState === 4) {
      if(this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
        callback.apply(this, [this.responseText, this]);
      } else {
        // something went wrong.
      }
    }
  };
  request.send();
}
```

And finally, you'd use the function, like this:

```
get("url/to/your/script", function(response) {
  // perform checks...
  window.eval(response);
});
```

**WARNING:** be very, ***VERY*** careful when using `eval`, don't ever `eval` something you don't trust and remember `eval` can be evil.

Comment: Hi just a question. I can get this content in php with no problem with a curl request. But as I stated in the comments above. I'm getting CORS problems. But I have the request response from php stored in a var. could I use the response text in php to set instead of the js ajax request? The only reason I ask is because when I feed that string directly into the eval im getting syntax errors

Comment: Since you're not maintaining the script, you  can't fix this problem. You'll have to contact who ever wrote the script  or the people who host it and notify them of what's going on.  The syntax  error is not caused by my answer (I double checked in jshint) and  if you're able to pass the string to eval then its not your code either.  This error is most likely caused  by the script you're trying to use, I'd suggest you start looking for  other options I'm sure there are plenty of open source projects that do what that script does, good luck.

Comment: Also, this is *kinda* shady, what kind of developer writes a JavaScript library but doesn't allow people to download/include it normally..? I'd suggest you do more research before including this library in a production environment.